# Core Data - fetching object

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

i have a tableViewController with some food names in it. 
when i click on the accessorybutton:
- it fetches the object in that row, open a detailViewController and pass in its init method, the string containing the name of the food object fetched.

the detailViewController let me edit the name, and with a delegate ( detailDidSaveText:(NSString *) )pass back the string value to the TableviewController

The tableViewController in it's delegate implementation wants to save the value.

if i had to create a new object would be easy, i would create a new managedobject and call NSEntitydescription insertnewentityforname.

but in this case i need to edit an object that already exists. so how can i do that?

how do i retrieve that object that i was editing ?

( i know the correct way would be to pass an object to the detailVC, but i'm doing some tests to better learn core data, and i would love to try this way also )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store a reference to your object

```
@property (nonatomic) Food *foodItemToEdit;
```

and set the property when the accessory button is tapped

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.foodItemToEdit = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Then in your delegate method, if the objectToEdit exists, create your food if it doesn't exist, then set it's text.

```
- (void)detailDidSaveText:(NSString *)text
{
    if (self.foodItemToEdit == nil) {
        self.foodItemToEdit = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Food" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
    }
    self.foodItemToEdit.text = text;
}
```